# Prove there is a bijection between the set of $R[x]$-module structures on $M$ and $\mathrm{End}_{R-\mathsf{Mod}}(M)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ a commutative ring and $M$ a $R$-module. Prove there is a bijection between the set of $R[x]$-module structures on $M$ and $\mathrm{End}_{R-\mathsf{Mod}}(M)$.

I really don't even know how to start with this question.

Comment: The action of $x$ on $M$ gives an $R$-endomorphism of $M$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How do I create a function that maps a module structure?

Comment: @george You take one module structure and then describe the module structure you make from it. Then you show it is a bijection.

Comment: @rschwieb yes but I mean, I can't even begin how to describe the map.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: an $R[x]$-module structure on $M$ is a map $F:R[x] \times M \to M$ satisfying certain properties, where you interpret $F(f(x), m) = f(x)\cdot m$ as the "multiplication." So, now you want to describe a mapping that takes $F$'s into module endomorphisms.

Comment: @George There aren't many likely candidates, and you have already been given a ton of hints about what the right one is. Your problem seems to be that you think you don't know how to choose the candidate.

Comment: I believe this is not true strictly speaking there should be a bijection between the set of $R[x]$ module structures on $M$ compatible with the $R$ module structure on $M$ and $\text{End}_{R}(M)$.

Comment: @rschwieb What is the action of the polynomial $x$ on an element $m \in M$?

Comment: @M.Van you are right, the R[x]-module structure has to extend the R-module structure already defined on M. It’s in the errata: https://www.math.fsu.edu/~aluffi/algebraerrata.2016/Errata.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $f\colon M\longrightarrow M$ is any  $R$-endomorphism of $M$, show the map
\begin{align}
R[X]\times M&\longrightarrow M\\
(P(X),m)&\longmapsto P(f)(m)
\end{align}
turns $M$ (with its group structure) into an $R[X]$-module.

Comment: By $P(f)(m)$ do you mean $P\circ f(m)$?

Comment: No: I mean the substitution of $f$ to the indeterminate, with the convention that powers of the indeterminate are converted to  symbolic powers of $f$ (for instance, $X^2\longleftrightarrow f\circ f$).

Comment: Ok, so I get how each $f\in End_R(M)$ uniquely determines an $R[X]$-module, but how can it be surjective?

Comment: If you have an $R[X]$-module structure, check multiplication by $X$ is an $R$-endomorphism of $M$.

Comment: @Bernard I wonder if the commutativity is crucial here

Comment: @ElmarGuseinov: As far as I know, polynomial rings are defined for commutative rings. Perhaps there exist extensions to the noncommutative case, but it certainly is not so simple t do as in the commutative case.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but I want to give another perspective on this fact...

Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring. It is well-known that if $S$ is a unital (not necessarily conmmutative) ring, and $\mu : R \to S$ is a fixed ring homomorphism, then for every $s \in S$ such that $$(\forall r \in R) \quad s\mu(r) = \mu(r)s$$ there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\mu_s : R[x] \to S$ that extends $\mu$ and sends $x$ to $s$. This is the universal property of the polynomial rings.

In other words, there is a bijection $$\{\nu \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Ring}}(R[x],S) : \nu|_R = \mu\} \longrightarrow \{s \in S : (\forall r \in R) \ s\mu(r) = \mu(r)s\}$$ given by $\nu \mapsto \nu(x)$ (with inverse $s \mapsto \mu_s$).

Now, when we consider an $R$-module $M$, let $S = \operatorname{End}_{\textsf{Ab}}(M)$ (recall, with point-wise addition and composition as multiplication) and $\mu : R \to S$ such that $\mu(r)(m) = rm$ for all $r \in R$ and $m \in M$. In this case, $\{\nu \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Ring}}(R[x],S) : \nu|_R = \mu\}$ is (in bijection with) the set of all $R[x]$-module structures on $M$ extending the given $R$-module structure, and $\{s \in S : (\forall r \in R) \ s\mu(r) = \mu(r)s\}$ is exactly the same as $\operatorname{End}_{R\textsf{-Mod}}(M)$.